# Is there a VSCode shortcut which tells me what command the next shortcut runs?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Like `Ctrl+h k` in emacs which when pressed waits for the next shortcut and then tells the user which command that shortcut runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search the keybindings, which amounts to the same thing, just a different user interface. If you are a Mac user, please understand <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> below as meaning <kbd>Cmd</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> – shows searchable key bindings

Now you can search/filter by description *or* keystroke. You have 2 ways to search by keystroke:

1. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> or click the icon of the little keyboard at the top right of the Keyboard Shortcut panel, then press the keys that you want to see the key binding for. The keyboard icon toggles keystroke recording mode. The recording mode is sticky; each time you revisit the Keyboard Shortcuts tab you can just press the keys you are interested in to see their bindings. Step by step:

   - When you press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key you will see `"ctrl"` displayed, and the recording mode continues to listen to what you type. Don't do this right now, but FYI, if you toggle keystroke recording mode now, and then remove the quotes around `"ctrl"`, you will see a sorted list of all the key chords bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
   - Next, when you add the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to the key chord, you then see `"ctrl+shift"` displayed. Again, don't do this right now, but FYI, if you toggle keystroke recording mode now, and then remove the quotes, you will see a sorted list of all the key chords bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
   - Finally, adding the <kbd>=</kbd> key to the key chord shows all the commands bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd>.
2. Type `ctrl` to see all the keybindings that start with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.
   Add a <kbd>+</kbd> and then a character to see what keybindings remain for that filter. For example, typing `Ctrl+x` shows 5 keybindings, the first of which is **Cut**.

Comment: Not really the same, because you have to type the shortcuts, instead of just pressing them which is much quicker, but thanks anyway. Someone should make an extension to do what emacs does if it's possible.

Comment: @Tom There is a button in the top right to capture the next key combo and use it for search